# Share works as like?

Tags: facebook, share, facebook-like

I've notice that when I share some content from my app on my time line, counter of people who like this page (like button is placed on page that I share) increment by 1. Of course it could be somebody wh like page while I'm sharing, butthere is not many users at testing phase under 10 visitors per day. tyr some times and it really looks loke share increment like counter. Does it true? Or may be I make some error and it works so now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The like button counter is made of the total of likes, shares and comments. If you want to know the number of likes only, you need to use FQL to query the like table.

Comment: Comments? It seems that every comment doesn't increment counter or it works more complicated?

Comment: Find in Facebook docs: `What makes up the number shown on my Like button?

The number shown is the sum of:

The number of likes of this URL
The number of shares of this URL (this includes copy/pasting a link back to Facebook)
The number of likes and comments on stories on Facebook about this URL
The number of inbox messages containing this URL as an attachment.`